# Magento: modifying the newsletter module

Tags: php, magento

The newsletter table of magento comes with first and last name fields but in the default setup only the email address is being saved. I'd like to make use of the first name field but am having a bit of trouble locating where the record is saved.

this is now what my form looks like:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
    <div class="block-content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="firstname"><?php echo $this->__('Name:') ?></label></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>" class="input-text" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label for="newsletter"><?php echo $this->__('Email:') ?></label></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up') ?></button>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</form>
```

There's a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155784/adding-a-custom-field-to-magentos-subscribtion-module) but I think it's now outdates as I can't seem to locate an _prepareSave function.

Can someone help in the right direction?

Thanks,
Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newsletter and subscriber tables don't contain firstname and lastname fields at least in the latest release, Magento EE 1.9.1.1.

If you want to add an additional field to the subscriber table, you should update the `subscribe` method of `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber` class (it receives just an e-mail address, you should pass additional arguments) and the controller `Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController`, action `newAction` so that it extracts other fields from $_POST array and uses in the creation of newsletter subscription (search for the instruction `$status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email)`).

Comment: yeah you're right, newsletter does have first and last names but they are only used for customers that register and check subscribe to newsletter. cheers

Comment: Hi can you expand your answer to where to find the classes and some examples for 1.9? Thanks. I am just starting Magento Development

Answer (score 2):

A bit easier solution for adding custom fields to Magento newsletter subscriber object can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155784/adding-a-custom-field-to-magentos-subscribtion-module/6425683#6425683)