# How to add extra Newsletter type in magento

Tags: magento-1.5, newsletter, magento

I want to add extra newsletter subscription type in magento.How can i do this ?

Currently i have only one option "**General Subscription**" But i want to add extra subscription types like
"**New Arrival**","**Weekly Update**".Please suggest me to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no admin interface by default in Magento for adding additional Newsletter Lists.
An excerpt from *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/newsletter.phtml*:

```
<ul class="form-list">
        <li class="control"><input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" id="subscription" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('General Subscription') ?>"<?php if($this->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" /><label for="subscription"><?php echo $this->__('General Subscription') ?></label></li>
    </ul>
```

As you can see, General Subscription is just a label for being subscribed to the newsletter.
More, the saveAction from app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/ManageController.php:

```
 try {
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->setIsSubscribed((boolean)$this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false))
        ->save();
        if ((boolean)$this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The subscription has been saved.'));
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The subscription has been removed.'));
        }
    }
```

treats is_subscribed as boolean (false/true) so your options are:

- Customize Magento (extend existing functionality)
- Find a suitable extension on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in commercial module then you can try AheadWorks Extension:
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-newsletter.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no embedded functionality to do this in Magento.

I am using Mailchimp's MageMonkey extension and their system for all my Newsletter and E-Mail related tasks.

It is easy to use and you can create lists (Groups) as much as you want.

Cheers

Comment: It also adds two fields that some already add. Advantageous but can cause extension conflicts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286218/1439760