# why adding observer not working with me in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, observers

thanks for reading, I'm trying to add new fields to newsletter in magento.
Made my search and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425683) which I think it's the most right one.
but when I added my observer, magento is not saving the new emails and some times the message

> There was a problem with the subscription

appears.
here is the code:
config.xml(were my module is My_test in local):

```
           <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <class>test/newsletter_observer</class>
                    <method>add</method>
                </observers>
            </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
```

and in file app/code/local/My/Test/Model/Newsletter/Observer.php :

```
class My_Test_Model_Newsletter_Observer{
   public function add($observer){
        // no thing here for now ..
    }
}
```

can any one help??
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@allGood, i see that you   have missing events name

```
 <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
      <observers>
      <my_newsletter>
        <class>test/newsletter_observer</class>
       <method>add</method>
     </my_newsletter>
    </observers>
  </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
```

more details:http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/

Comment: thanks .. This is because I'm still new to magento :)