# Save event on Magento custom admin extension

Tags: magento

I'm working on extension that adds extra tab in admin panel and when save button
is pressed some custom product attributes needs to be updated.
Can you provide me some guidelines on how to catch that event and make that update based on
the data field of that extension.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you add a tab? To the product tab? If you added the product attributes the right way, they should be displayed and saved automatically. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-create-attribute-in-magento-useful-for-the-on-the-fly-import-system/

Comment: It will be at System -> Colnfiguration. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There is an event: `model_config_data_save_before` you may use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a "custom event" that you catch and then do some code.

To do this follow these steps:

1) Create a custom event see [here](http://phpflow.com/php/how-to-define-custom-event-in-magento/)

2) After creating the event you need to "dispatch" it (this lets the system know that the event happened)

Use the following code to dispatch event:

```
  Mage::dispatchEvent("your_custom_event", array('name_you_want_to_access_it_by' => $importantVariable));
```

3) Then to catch the event we just created set up an observer to catch it (see this question: [What is the correct way to set up an observer in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048458/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-up-an-observer-in-magento) )

4) Do whatever you want (well almost anything)

Comment: I think this is it. I'll try this and report about the results here. Thank you for your reply.